# difference between Drawee and ImagePipeline in Fresco Image Loading Library

Tags: android, fresco

I am using Fresco Image Loader in my application in which uri is loaded into `SimpleDraweeView`. I have a list of images, sometimes i load the same image into two different views. In this case does fresco loads the image from cache into `SimpleDraweeView` or does it downloads the image from the network whenever needed and also where exactly do i need to use `Drawee` and `ImagePipeline`. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fresco library is built specifically to address concerns like this. To answer your first question, no, the image won't be downloaded twice. It won't even be decoded twice. Fresco avoids doing any duplicate work. You should be completely fine in using the same uri in multiple views at the same time.

As for your other question, Drawee operates on an API level above ImagePipeline. Those two are not competing. ImagePipeline is to Drawee as a Wheel is to a Car. If you want to display the image you should be using Drawee and not ImagePipeline. If you need to get the actual image bytes or to do something else with the Bitmap other than displaying it, you should use the ImagePipeline.